# why is my gearbox still grinding after a full new clutch kit and a gearbox refurbishnemt?

Tags: transmission, clutch, vauxhall, astra, grinding

I have a 65-plate Vauxhall Astra Sri. I've had this car for less than two years and have already replaced the full clutch kit once(£1300). 11 months after this (December 2022) I had issues where it wasn't going into gear once the engine was up to temperature. I took it to the garage and they sent the gearbox off to be fully refurbished and changed the full clutch kit again (£1600) I have had the car back for less than a week and sometimes the gears are stiff when changing, just like I had before the gearbox was refurbished. is this down to the gearbox and clutch needing to settle and wear in? or could there be another issue going on? the car is only worth around £7000 and with how much I've already spent on it, I'm starting to question if the car is worth all of the work I'm needing to do to it. (a little background, I look after this car like it's my child, don't rag it around, I always get it serviced on time and keep it spotless, there is no way that I'm burning through the transmission system through driver error. I bought the car on 36,000 miles and it currently has 59,000 miles. with one previous owner)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

- Was the clutch master/slave ever looked at?
- Is there enough hydraulic fluid in it? (I don't know if your vehicle shares off of the brake reservoir.)
- Has hydraulic system ever been bled?
- If the hydraulic line between the master & slave isn't working right, it could be bulging and not giving you enough to fully disengage the clutch with pedal fully depressed.

I've also seen where the area of the firewall where the master is mounted was starting to bust out, which allowed the master to push out and not allowing full pedal travel.

Comment: The slave cylinder was replaced with the clutch and flywheel if that's what you mean?

Comment: That's what I mean, but usually it isn't replaced with clutch work. The throwout bearing is replaced, but not the slave ... not saying it wasn't. If it was replaced and not bled properly, it could be the source of your issues.